# How do I make a tkinter.Entry extend to the right hand side of the window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

I am creating a cryptogram game using tkinter in python 3 that takes a title, phrase, number of giveaway letters, and the giveaway letters themselves as inputs.

The window currently looks like this:
[tkinter inputs window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T0Sa.png)

The problem is, that I want the white entry boxes to start from the end of the label on the left, and extend all the way to the end of the window.

Like this:
[desired input window design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot2MU.png)

I am currently using the `.pack()` method to place objects in the window, with rows and columns.

In total, there are 4 rows and two columns:

row1: titleLabel, titleEntry

row2: phraseLabel, phraseEntry

row3: numGiveawayLettersLabel, numGiveawayLettersEntry

row4: giveawayLettersLabel, (not sure what this will be yet, but it will take in the giveaway letters)

***My Code:***

```
global windowBackgroundColour
windowBackgroundColour = "#5A9AD7"

def createUserInputsWindow():
    global userInputsWindow
    global windowBackgroundColour
    # specifies what global variables tihs method is using

    # -------------------- Creates User Inputs Window --------------------

    userInputsWindow = tkinter.Tk()
    userInputsWindow.configure(bg=windowBackgroundColour)
    userInputsWindow.title("The Puzzle Club")

    # -------------------- Creates Frames (Containers) --------------------

    userInputsWindowRow1 = tkinter.Frame(userInputsWindow)
    userInputsWindowRow1Column1 = tkinter.Frame(userInputsWindowRow1)
    userInputsWindowRow1Column2 = tkinter.Frame(userInputsWindowRow1)

    userInputsWindowRow2 = tkinter.Frame(userInputsWindow)
    userInputsWindowRow2Column1 = tkinter.Frame(userInputsWindowRow2)
    userInputsWindowRow2Column2 = tkinter.Frame(userInputsWindowRow2)

    userInputsWindowRow3 = tkinter.Frame(userInputsWindow)
    userInputsWindowRow3Column1 = tkinter.Frame(userInputsWindowRow3)
    userInputsWindowRow3Column2 = tkinter.Frame(userInputsWindowRow3)

    userInputsWindowRow4 = tkinter.Frame(userInputsWindow)
    userInputsWindowRow4Column1 = tkinter.Frame(userInputsWindowRow4)
    userInputsWindowRow4Column2 = tkinter.Frame(userInputsWindowRow4)

    # -------------------- Populating Frames (Containers) --------------------

    userInputsWindowRow1.pack(side="top", fill="both")
    userInputsWindowRow1Column1.pack(side="left", fill="both")
    userInputsWindowRow1Column2.pack(side="right", fill="both")

    userInputsWindowRow2.pack(side="top", fill="both")
    userInputsWindowRow2Column1.pack(side="left", fill="both")
    userInputsWindowRow2Column2.pack(side="right", fill="both")

    userInputsWindowRow3.pack(side="top", fill="both")
    userInputsWindowRow3Column1.pack(side="left", fill="both")
    userInputsWindowRow3Column2.pack(side="right", fill="both")

    userInputsWindowRow4.pack(side="top", fill="both")
    userInputsWindowRow4Column1.pack(side="left", fill="both")
    userInputsWindowRow4Column2.pack(side="right", fill="both")

    userInputsWindowRow1.configure(bg=userInputsWindow.cget("bg"))
    userInputsWindowRow2.configure(bg=userInputsWindow.cget("bg"))
    userInputsWindowRow3.configure(bg=userInputsWindow.cget("bg"))
    userInputsWindowRow4.configure(bg=userInputsWindow.cget("bg"))

    userInputsWindow.resizable(width=False, height=False)



    # -------------------- Creating Widgets --------------------

    titleLabel = tkinter.Label(userInputsWindowRow1Column1, text="Title:")
    titleLabel.configure(fg="black", bg=userInputsWindowRow1.cget("bg"), font="none 32")
    # This creates a title label, that has the text - "Title:"

    phraseLabel = tkinter.Label(userInputsWindowRow2Column1, text="Phrase:")
    phraseLabel.configure(fg="black", bg=userInputsWindowRow2.cget("bg"), font="none 32")
    # This crates a phrase label, that has the text - "Phrase:"

    numGiveawayLettersLabel = tkinter.Label(userInputsWindowRow3Column1, text="# of Giveaway Letters:")
    numGiveawayLettersLabel.configure(fg="black", bg=userInputsWindowRow3.cget("bg"), font="none 32")
    # This creates a label that has the text - "# of Giveaway Letters:"

    giveawayLettersLabel = tkinter.Label(userInputsWindowRow4Column1, text="Giveaway Letters:")
    giveawayLettersLabel.configure(fg="black", bg=userInputsWindowRow4.cget("bg"), font="none 32")
    # This creates a label that has the text - "Giveaway Letters:"

    titleEntry = tkinter.Entry(userInputsWindowRow1Column2, font=titleLabel.cget("font"))
    titleEntry.insert(0, "Enter title")
    # This creates an entry box for the user to enter the title of their puzzle in

    phraseEntry = tkinter.Entry(userInputsWindowRow2Column2, font=phraseLabel.cget("font"))
    phraseEntry.insert(0, "Enter Phrase")
    # This creates an entry box for the user to enter the phrase they wish to use in the puzzle

    numGiveawayLettersEntry = tkinter.Entry(userInputsWindowRow3Column2, font=numGiveawayLettersLabel.cget("font"))
    numGiveawayLettersEntry.insert(0, "(1 - 26)")
    # This creates an entry box for the user to enter how many giveaway letters they wish to have

    # -------------------- Populating Widgets --------------------

    titleLabel.pack(side="left", fill="both")
    phraseLabel.pack(side="left", fill="both")
    numGiveawayLettersLabel.pack(side="left", fill="both")
    giveawayLettersLabel.pack(side="left", fill="both")

    titleEntry.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    phraseEntry.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    numGiveawayLettersEntry.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    return
```

Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

(There are lots of functions in my code and some global variables may not have been referenced in the code above, if you need the full code, please message me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use one frame per row. You're already doing that, but it's much easier if you use a function or a class. The only thing you're missing is that you need to use the `fill` option both for each entry and each frame.

Example using a class:

```
class InputRow(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, text, help_text):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master, background=master.cget("background"))
        self.label = tkinter.Label(self, text=text, background=master.cget("background"))
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.label.pack(side="left")
        self.entry.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.entry.insert(0, help_text)

    def get(self):
        return self.entry.get()
```

You could then create the labels and entries like this:

```
rows = [
    InputRow(userInputsWindow, "Title:", "Enter title"),
    InputRow(userInputsWindow, "Phrase:", "Enter Phrase"),
    InputRow(userInputsWindow, "# of Giveaway Letters:", "(1-26)"),
    InputRow(userInputsWindow, "Giveaway Letters:", ""),
]

for row in rows:
    row.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

Comment: From looking at your answer, I can see that, while I extended the entry, I failed to extend the column that the entry was in. I changed this and now it seems to work: `userInputsWindowRow1Column2.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)`